Ошибка при компиляции кода в CodeBlocks в Linux | error: ld returned 1 exit status|
Скачал CodeBlocks в Linux и пытаюсь скомпилировать простой файл Hello World! программа,  показывает ошибку:
||=== Build: Debug in pr (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
||cannot find obj/Debug/main.o: No such file or directory|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Папка с программой находится на рабочем столе.
НАСТРОЙКИ КОМПИЛЯТОР:



Может быть из-за того что у меня в пусто в пункте Resource compiler (См. картинку №3)
Build Projects

РЕШЕНИЙ:
Проблема была в том что в пути по которому лежит программа был русский(кириллический) символ. Я переименовал символ на английский символ и все заработало!

А Вы компилятор и make в системе установили? Лучше сразу ставить пакет build-essential (если у Вас linux - какая-то из бубунтов) - он установит что надо для сборки программ через gcc. "Компилятор ресурсов" - это про сборку программ с графическим интерфейсом, для хелловорлда он не нужен.

@Vladimir я установил пакет
sudo apt install build-essential Но это не помогло. Может в настройках компилятора нужно путь к компилятору прописать?

А просто в консоли программа компилируется? Командой типа `gcc main.c -o hello'. Если да, тогда надо внимательнее смотреть настройки проекта. Может в настройках компилятора нужно путь к компилятору прописать - путь там вроде как указан.

@Vladimir в консоль зашел в директорию с программой написал gcc -o main main.c далее ввел ./main и Hello world! вывелось.  А почему тогда в CodeBlocks не компилирует?

Раз в консоли программа собралась, то значит компилятор и make установлены нормально. Вы build-essential установили до создания проекта в C::B или после? Возможно, в параметрах сборки (меню Project->Build options) проекта используется не тот (отсутствующий) компилятор..

@Vladimir я добавил картинку Build Projects. Build-essential я вроде бы скачал после установки C::B

Вопрос был не про установку, а про создание проекта. Попробуйте тогда просто создать новый проект. И на всякий случай выполните в консоли команду which gcc - если вдруг gcc будет не в /usr/bin/, то тогда надо будет исправить путь к компилятору в настройках C::B.

@Vladimir gcc у меня в /usr/bin/gcc. А как путь к компилятору исправить ?

Этот путь верный, не надо ничего исправлять. По идее, в новых проектах все должно работать.

@Vladimir Проблема была в том что в пути по которому лежит программа был русский(кириллический) символ. Я переименовал символы на английский символ и все заработало!

Проблема была в том что в пути по которому лежит программа был русский(кириллический) символ. Я переименовал символ на английский символ и все заработало!
